# Looping through multiple nested JSON arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following structure for my JSON array. i would like to access the value of the key ERRORS. Till now i have not been able to reach this value by using for each loops.

if someone could explain me their thought process that would be very helpful for me because i have been stuck on this problem for a while now and cant seem to get any wiser.

I would like to return every ERROR in the nested Json arrays :)

Json array:

```
[
 {
  "RESPONSE": {
      "Result": [
       {
        "ERRORS":"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049"
       }
      ]
    }
  }
,{"RESPONSE":{"Result":[{"ERRORS":"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211048"}]}}]
```

My code:

```
        $data = Log::all('RESPONSE');
        $results_decoded = json_decode($data, true);
        $json_result= $results_decoded[0];
        foreach($results_decoded as $elem){
                foreach ($json_result['RESPONSE']["Result"] as $result) {
//                      $error = $result['ERROR'];
                return($result);
                }
        };
```

code returns:

```
{
"ERRORS": "99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049"
}
```

Comment: If you want to get the ERRORS from _all_ objects, then `return` inside the loop makes little sense to begin with. And why are you passing `&$result` as a reference? That would only be necessary, f you wanted to _modify_ the contents of the data structure from within the loop.

Comment: `foreach($data as $item) { var_dump($item["RESPONSE"]["Result"][0]["ERRORS"]); }` - assuming that below `Result`, there will only ever be one array item. If there could be multiple at this point, you will have to use a second loop for that level.

Answer (score 1):

If you use return inside the foreach it will break after the first loop.
I would suggest you using array_map instead, so your code could look similar to:

```
    $data = Log::all('RESPONSE');

    try {
        $decodedResponse = json_decode($data, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
    } catch (JsonException $e) {
        $decodedResponse = [];
    }

    return array_map(static fn(array $responseData): array => $responseData['RESPONSE']['Result']['ERRORS'], $decodedResponse);
```

This will filter out "ERRORS" branch from your array and will return new one with found values.

If you want to stay with the foreach loop, just store results in some variable and return it after it:

```
    $data = Log::all('RESPONSE');
    $results_decoded = json_decode($data, true);

    $errors = [];

    foreach($results_decoded as $element){
        foreach ($element['RESPONSE']["Result"] as $result) {
            $errors[] = $result['ERROR'];

        }
    };

    return $errors;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried your solution and it seems that it only iterates over 1 because i keep getting the same values back. Would you know any fix for this? ```[
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049",]```

Comment: Sorry just realized that second solution made no sense ;) I updated the answer, and should be better now. If it still will not do a job for you, show me dump from $results_decoded